# Adjust two text box width

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, width

I'm a beginner of html form designer, I would like make a simple `input-group` in the html, which the output which text box **width** is different
That mean which **surname** textbox is **shorter** and **FullName** is **longer**
can you advise how to do it ?

```
<div class="row h-100">
 <div class="col">
   <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text" id="">First and last name</span>
           </div>
           <input type="text" id="surname" class="form-control" style="width:80px">
           <input type="text" id="FullName" class="form-control" style="width:100%">
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Add the same width for input 's tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row h-100">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="">First and last name</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" id="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Mr" style="width:80px;flex-grow: 0;">
      <input type="text" id="FullName" class="form-control" placeholder="">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks , flex-grow is the key work on it, if I want to make the last name width extend to form width, The example is that
Code : [            ]    Date : [              ]     Type : [                 ]
First and Last Name : [       ][                                             ]
How can do it ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: can you explain a bit more please?

Answer (score 0):

You Forgot to remove this **enter code here** text in your surname field `class="form-control"`

```html
<div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text" id="">First and last name</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="surname" class="form-control" style="width:80px">
        <input type="text" id="FullName" class="form-control" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```